# Calling external script on breakpoint with Register Values as parameters

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I would like to script Trace32 so I can dump register state and pass to my script on a breakpoint trigger.

I am currently looking at the /CMD flag.

Is there any way I can set a breakpoint in the format of this:

```
Break.set main /CMD "OS.Command MyScript.sh $R0 $R1 $R2 ..."
```

where I am dumping the registers and passing it to MyScript as parameters.

My backup plan is to use wp.Register and have my script monitor file system instead.

Thanks ahead for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this solution.

When setting the breakpoint, instead use `/CMD "DO bkpt_trigger.cmm"`

Then in bkpt_trigger.cmm

```
&r0=Register(R0)
&r1=Register(R1)
...
Os.Command echo &r0 &r1
```